# How to update <byte, string> dictionary in MongoDB Document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I update the representation of a <byte,string> Dictionary property in a BSON Document? I don't see how to do it with the BSON types. The object was stored using the automatic BSON serialization and I want to replace the entire Dictionary.

Let's say we've got this class:

```
public class Message  
{
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<byte, string> Contents {get;set;}
}
```

in MongoDB it looks something like this for the message collection:

```
{
  _id :  12345,
  Text : "This is a text",
  Contents: [ [1 : "true"], [3 : "youtube"] ]
}
```

The update should look like this

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", messageId);
var update = Update.Set("Contents", -> how to build me?);
MessageCollection.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: Try searching this [mongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/) about BSON documents.

Comment: And I don't have time to tell you, that the anwser can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

Comment: I am a little confused: What is the question here?  Does this code (and the code in your other comment below) run?  What happens when you run it?

Comment: The question is: How to serialize a <byte,string> Dictionary and then update only the dictionary party for an existing document in MongoDB? Should be a simple one if you are not new to the client driver like me? Or just answer the "how to build me?" from above with a piece of code.  

The code in my answer below works but it is to much overhead as I'm serializing the complete message object every time just to get the "Contents" Dictionary updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm serializing the full message object now and take the dictionary part out then for the update.

```
var messageDoc = new BsonDocument();
var bsonWriter = BsonWriter.Create(messageDoc);
BsonSerializer.Serialize<Message>(bsonWriter, message);

var query = Query.EQ("_id", messageId);
var update = Update.Set("Contents", messageDoc["Contents"]);
MessageCollection.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: A bit late but `SetWrapped` I believe will take a non-mongo object and do all the mappings automatically. Might have been able to do what you wanted here but I assume a year and a half later its probably already long forgotten... Leaving this here for the next person to come across this problem though.